# how to change output 0/1 row into names like Assignment / Examination

Tags: c

I want to know how to change the output for sum and avg from 0 and 1 row into assignment and examination. I have done the coding but don’t know how to change the code only for this output, please help. Below is my code.

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i][j] ;

        avg = sum/2;

    }




    printf("Total of the %d row Marks is = %.2f\n\n",i, sum);
    printf("Average of the %d row Marks is = %.2f\n\n",i, avg);;

    sum = 0;
    avg = 0;
```

expecting below result

```
Total of the Assignment Marks is = 11.00

Average of the Examination Marks is = 5.50

Total of the Assignment Marks is = 15.00

Average of the Examination Marks is = 7.50
```

but I'm getting this:

```
Total of the 0 row Marks is = 11.00

Average of the 0 row Marks is = 5.50

Total of the 1 row Marks is = 15.00

Average of the 1 row Marks is = 7.50
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to its core. It also help to provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask] as well. These should all help you understand why your question is downvoted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ternary operator

e.g.

```
printf("Total of the %s row Marks is = %.2f\n\n", (i == 0? "Assignment Marks" : "Examination Marks"), sum);
```

Similar for the other `printf`